# Generate random numbers and update in XML file using Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, xml, robotframework

I've two XML files in which I manually change the values before proceeding with further evaluation. I would like to know how should I be able to update the values in the XML file using Robot Framework.

I've used faker library to generate random number but I don't know how to update them in XML. The first XML file is something like this:

```
<dns:ManageRequest>
    <SPResource>
        <ID>ORD452257337191</ID>
        <interactionDate>2016-09-20T02:35:30Z</interactionDate>
        <orderType>Connect</orderType>
        <SPResourceComprisedOf>
            <DescribedBy>
                <value>CLI0000000000191</value>
                <Characteristic>
                    <ID>clientID</ID>
                </Characteristic>
            </DescribedBy>
            <DescribedBy>
                <value>TOW566105009191</value>
                <Characteristic>
                    <ID>ticketOfWorkId</ID>
                </Characteristic>
            </DescribedBy>
        </SPResourceComprisedOf>
    </SPResource>
</dns:ManageRequest>
```

and the second xml file looks like this:

```
<dns:ManageOrder>
    <FieldWork>
        <ID>WOR140618136785</ID>
        <Priority>
            <priorityValues>45</priorityValues>
        </Priority>
        <baseRevisionNumber>-1</baseRevisionNumber>
        <FieldWorkSpecifiedBy>
            <ID>Activation</ID>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <type>WorkOrder Specification</type>
        </FieldWorkSpecifiedBy>
        <FieldWorkOverview>
            <DescribedBy>
                <value>WRQ140618136785</value>
                <Characteristic>
                    <ID>Work Request ID</ID>
                    <type>Overview</type>
                </Characteristic>
            </DescribedBy>
            <DescribedBy>
                <value>ORD452257337191</value>
                <Characteristic>
                    <ID>Reference ID</ID>
                    <type>Overview</type>
                </Characteristic>
            </DescribedBy>
        </FieldWorkOverview>
    </FieldWork>
</dns:ManageOrder>
```

In the firs XML file the values of ORD, CLI & TOW needs to be changed and in the second XML file WOR & WRQ need to be changed but the value of ORD in the second file needs to same as the value of ORD in first file.

I really appreciate any help, because I am really lost in this now :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use lxml library.

Link: https://pypi.org/project/lxml/

This is example for edit element ID with your value ORD452257337191 to value '123456'.

Code:

```
${file}=  get file  ${path_to_file}  encoding=UTF-8

${xml_file}=  parse xml  ${file}

set element text  ${xml_file}  123456  xpath=ID

save xml  ${xml_file}  ${path_to_file}  encoding=UTF-8
```